# Oracle Form showing error ORA-01422 more than one record

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
IF :CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL AND :BRANCH_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
    DECLARE
        X_NO           NUMBER;
        X_VOUCHER_ID   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            GL_VOUCHER_ID
        INTO X_VOUCHER_ID
        FROM
            SM_SALES_INVOICES SI,
            AR_CUSTOMERS AC,
            GL_VOUCHERS GV
        WHERE
            AC.CUSTOMER_ID = SI.CUSTOMER_ID
            AND SI.GL_VOUCHER_ID = GV.VOUCHER_ID
            AND SI.CUSTOMER_ID = :CUSTOMER_ID;

        UPDATE GL_VOUCHERS
        SET
            BRANCH_ID = :NEW_BRANCH_ID
        WHERE
            VOUCHER_ID = X_VOUCHER_ID;

        MESSAGE('Branch is changed sucessfully!');
        MESSAGE('Branch is changed sucessfully!');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            NULL;
    END;

    COMMIT;
ELSE
    MESSAGE('Please Enter Both Fields!');
    MESSAGE('Please Enter both Fields!');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that your first `SELECT` query is returning multiple records and you are trying to store multiple results into single variable `X_VOUCHER_ID`.

You need to update the table `GL_VOUCHERS` without saving `GL_VOUCHER_ID` into `X_VOUCHER_ID` as following:

> ```
> IF :CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL AND :BRANCH_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
>     DECLARE
>         X_NO           NUMBER;
>         -- removed following variable
>         -- X_VOUCHER_ID   NUMBER;
>     BEGIN
>     --REMOVED THIS SELECT CLAUSE
>     --        SELECT
>     --            GL_VOUCHER_ID
>     --        INTO X_VOUCHER_ID
>     --        FROM
>     --            SM_SALES_INVOICES SI,
>     --            AR_CUSTOMERS AC,
>     --            GL_VOUCHERS GV
>     --        WHERE
>     --            AC.CUSTOMER_ID = SI.CUSTOMER_ID
>     --            AND SI.GL_VOUCHER_ID = GV.VOUCHER_ID
>     --            AND SI.CUSTOMER_ID = :CUSTOMER_ID;
>         UPDATE GL_VOUCHERS
>         SET
>             BRANCH_ID = :NEW_BRANCH_ID
>         WHERE
>             VOUCHER_ID IN ( -- ADDED THIS IN CLAUSE
>                 SELECT
>                     GL_VOUCHER_ID
>                 FROM
>                     SM_SALES_INVOICES SI,
>                     AR_CUSTOMERS AC,
>                     GL_VOUCHERS GV
>                 WHERE
>                     AC.CUSTOMER_ID = SI.CUSTOMER_ID
>                     AND SI.GL_VOUCHER_ID = GV.VOUCHER_ID
>                     AND SI.CUSTOMER_ID = :CUSTOMER_ID
>             );
>
>         MESSAGE('Branch is changed sucessfully!');
>         MESSAGE('Branch is changed sucessfully!');
>     EXCEPTION
>         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
>             NULL;
>     END;
>
>     COMMIT;
> ELSE
>     MESSAGE('Please Enter Both Fields!');
>     MESSAGE('Please Enter both Fields!');
> END IF;
> ```

The above code will update all the records of the `GL_VOUCHERS` table which matches the `GL_VOUCHER_ID` from an inner subquery.

Cheers!!

Comment: Sir it's done Thank you so much for your response now it's working fine what I want... :)